# is there a method to check if string exist in another dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

i have a dataframe :

```
name ; id ; address
DR LUCAS FERNANDEZ ;  NEW YORK, AM ST543
JOHN FELLA MD ;  CANADA STREET 73663
```

and i have another dataframe like :

```
firstname ; lastname ; city ; ID_K
LUCAS ; FERNANDEZ ; NEW YORK ; 987
JAMES ; BRON ; PARIS ; 7655
```

i want to get the ID_K from the second dataframe if "firstname" AND "lastname" (df2) are in "name" (df1)  AND city (df2) is in address (df1)

i want to have in output

```
name ; id ; address   ; searched_id
DR LUCAS FERNANDEZ ;  NEW YORK, AM ST543 ; 987
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` to create all combinations then filter rows:

```
get_id = lambda x: x['firstname'] in x['name'] \
                   and x['lastname'] in x['name'] \
                   and x['city'] in x['address']

out = df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
out = out.loc[out.apply(get_id, axis=1), df1.columns.tolist() + ['ID_K']]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                 name              address  ID_K
0  DR LUCAS FERNANDEZ   NEW YORK, AM ST543   987
```

Setup:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['DR LUCAS FERNANDEZ', 'JOHN FELLA MD'],
                    'address': [' NEW YORK, AM ST543', ' CANADA STREET 73663']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'firstname': ['LUCAS', 'JAMES'],
                    'lastname': ['FERNANDEZ', 'BRON'],
                    'city': ['NEW YORK', 'PARIS'],
                    'ID_K': [987, 7655]}
```

Comment: thank you but i have an error MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False

Comment: I think you forgot the `how='cross'` parameter or your version of pandas is too old to support `cross` method.

Comment: how can i update pandas ?

Comment: `pip install -U pandas` for a Python environment or `conda update pandas` for an Anaconda environment. You should also have a recent of Python version.